# How to display an UIAlertView after a iOS push notification everywhere except in one view

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uialertview

I'm trying to do a little messenger, I would like to display an alert saying that a new message has been received everywhere on the app except on the conversation itself. For now my alert is displayed everywhere, is it possible to filter it so it is not displayed on the ConversationDetailController?

Here is my code in appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    var mess:String?
    var displayName:String?


    if let result = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {

        if let alert = result["alert"] as? String {

            mess = alert

            if let extra = userInfo["extra"] as? NSDictionary
            {

                if let name = extra["displayName"] as? String
                {

                    displayName = name

                    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "You have a new message from \(displayName!)", message: mess, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alert.show()

                }

            }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("newMessageReceived", object: nil)

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How are your view controllers presented? The simplest solution to your question is to check self.window.rootViewController, but if you're using a container (such as UITabBarController or UINavigationController), this won't be the viewController you're looking for

Comment: My ConversationDetailTableViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController unfortunately :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

1. Create a new class which is an alert presentation manager
2. Create an instance of this class when you receive a notification
3. Move all of the alert logic into that class
4. The app delegate posts the `newMessageReceived` notification and passes the presentation manager as the object
5. Anyone who observes the notification can interrogate the presentation manager for details about the notification and cancel the presentation
6. If anyone cancels then the notification isn't shown
7. After posting the notification the app delegate asks the presentation manager to `presentAlertIfAppropriate` (which checks if it's been cancelled)

Notifications are sent to all observers directly, so at this point in time you can post the notification and immediately check if presentation is required. It may be better to allow a little time for recipients of the notification to decide about cancellation but things get a good deal more complicated if you need to do something like that...

Comment: I understand in theory but I'm very new to iOS and I'm struggling to do that in practice, could you show me an example of implementation by any chance?

Comment: Maybe an idea to create a new question and show the code, how far have you got? You created the new class? Gave it a property for the `displayName`? Added a method to `displayAlertIfRequired`?